# A relation between derived subgroups and powers of a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group. I am interested in to finding a relation between derived subgroups of $G$ and powers of $G$.
More precisely, I guess $\forall n\in \mathbb{N},\exists
 k\in  \mathbb{N} $ such that $G^{(n)}=\langle G^{p_1p_2...p_k}\rangle$ where $G^{(n)}$ is the n-th derived subgroup and $p_1,...,p_k$ are prime divisors (not necessarily distinct) of $G$ and $G^{p_1p_2...p_k}=\{x^{p_1...p_k}|\forall x\in G\}.$

For example let $G=\mathbb{S}_4$, then we have

$G^{'}=\mathbb{A}_4=\langle{\mathbb{S}_4}^{2}\rangle$,
$G^{(2)}=\mathbb{V}=\langle{\mathbb{S}_4}^{6}\rangle$ and $G^{(3)}=1=\langle{\mathbb{S}_4}^{12}\rangle.$
This is the desired conclusion.

Can anybody help me to solve this problem for every finite group $G$?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Who said there is a relation in the first place?

Comment: ِDear Ivan,  I have not seen this before, but just guess.Because For every example that I checked was true.

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never, they say.

Take a direct product of two very familiar groups: $G=S_3\times\mathbb Z_6$. Now $G'=A_3$, which is **not** among the powers of $G$ at all.